# how to pass textbox text details to database connection string c#

Tags: c#, database

I have a application where I want to pass user entered username password port servicename in textboxes to connection string, so that I can use it for Oracle database connection.

example :

```
string conString = "User Id=hr;Password=hr;Data Source=localhost:1523/orcl.162.0.7;";
```

in place of `User Id` `hr => textuser_id.Text` value
in place of `password` `hr => textpass.Text` value

Comment: You will be in danger by this construction of such connection strings

Comment: show me the way how to do it my friend

Comment: Look at the class SqlConnectionStringBuilder or the equivalent one for your database engine

Answer (score 0):

Embedding username and passwords in your application is never a good idea. Mainly because most code ends up in code repositories such as github and you do not want user and passwords visable to other teams in your company, or other github users. All it takes is accidentally making a repo public and suddenly any one can access your database. 
Some alternatives include

1. Pull them from a key vault such as azure key vault or HashiCorp vault
2. Pull them from the systems environment variables [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8) if they will run on a server
3. Then as the gentlemen recommended above suggested you can use a SqlConnectionStringBuilder to put the user and password together in the string

However for your knowledge on how you can manipulate strings some examples include

```
        public string CreateConnectionString(string user, string password)
        {
            string optionOne = "User Id="+user+";Password="+password+";Data Source=localhost:1523/orcl.162.0.7;";

            // String interpolation
            string optionTwo = $"User Id={user};Password={password};Data Source=localhost:1523/orcl.162.0.7;";
                // Many more ways 
            return optionTwo;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Format:

```
string constring = string.Format("User Id={0};Password={1};Data Source=localhost:1523/orcl.162.0.7;", textuser_id.Text, textpass.Text);
```

You can also use $ in front of your string:

```
string constring = $"User Id={textuser_id.Text};Password={textpass.Text};Data Source=localhost:1523/orcl.162.0.7;";
```

The difference:

- string.Format: use numbers inside the {} which indicate the location of the value after the string.
- $: use the values inside the {}.

For me it is easier to use the $, but you can use both.

Good luck!

Comment: bro i want to take localhost,1523,orcl... also from textbox only

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: rom_totach i want to pass the localhost , portno, service name from textbox only as user enter the details in textbox the values should be passed to the connection string and on button click the connection should happen ... i dont want hardcoded values for connection string

Comment: There is no reason for you to do that.. But anyway: double click on the text box and it should automatically create a method of what happens when the text is changed in the text box. You can do whatever you want from there.